# Scalar variable when using class

Tags: c#, sql

Do I need to add all the parameter I intend to use throughout the code in the class that have the SqlCommand, or can I pass the parameters when I call for the class?

In my Class file (Called DataAccess):

```
public static int SqlGetInt(string queryString)
    {
        int retVal = 0;

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = GetConnection())
            {
                cn.Open();
                using (SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, cn))
                    {
                        cmd.Transaction = tr;

                        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (rdr.Read())
                                retVal = GetRdrInt(rdr, 0);
                        }
                    }
                    tr.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
```

in my Form1 code:

```
string sql = "SELECT ID FROM tbl_employees WHERE username = @username";
        _responsible_id = DataAccess.SqlGetInt(sql);
```

Since I havent added the parameters, this ofcourse fails. So back to my question: Can I add these parameters in my Form1 file when I call for SqlGetInt() or do I need to add it in the SqlGetInt() in the Class file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General purpose procedures to query database are always bad (my opinion) because they lack the flexibility required by the complexity of the real world problems.

In your case you could change your procedure to something like this

```
public static int SqlGetInt(string queryString, List<SqlParameter> parms = null)
{
    int retVal = 0;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = GetConnection())
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, cn))
                {
                    cmd.Transaction = tr;
                    if(parms != null)
                       cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parms.ToArray());

                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (rdr.Read())
                            retVal = GetRdrInt(rdr, 0);
                    }
                }
                tr.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

You add a parameter for a `List<SqlParameter>` and leave it optional (so your existing code works without changes). This list if is not null could be added to the parameters collection of your command. 
Of course, after this, when you need parameters, then you need to create your parameter list whenever you call this method.

```
string sql = "SELECT ID FROM tbl_employees WHERE username = @username";
List<SqlParameter> pl = new List<SqlParameter>();
pl.Add(new SqlParameter() 
{
    ParameterName="@username",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
    Value = txtUserName.Text;

};
_responsible_id = DataAccess.SqlGetInt(sql, pl);
```